# Searching HTML files in a directory for text

Tags: parsing, search, text, full-text-search

Ok, I'm very new to programming but am understanding how to conceptualize and talk about what I want and need to learn and find better.

Right now I am working with a directory `/Food` and have `.html` pages that I've downloaded from several sites.

I'd like to create a script to basically use the directory `/Food` and all files in this folder and its sub-directories, and compare the text for files that contain the same strings I input.

**So something like:**

```
commandforsearchingtextfiles  [option for directory]/food *.[or command for all files following this directory path]

salt (string1)
sugar (string 2)
flour (string 3)

echo results
```

The results/output should be the files that contain the strings... and if you can add extra ideas on how to organize the output

Again, if this is covered, please just point me in the right locations of where to learn about this but if you have any quick advice or a quick script, that would be great too.

Comment: What programming language do you intend to use?

Answer (score 1):

You on linux? Or could use cygwin (if on windows)?

... if so the basic linux commands would cope with this pretty well.

eg to search for all files containing salt...

```
find Food/ -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 grep salt
```

can narrow/widen the search by adding more switches to the various commands, eg case insensitive:

```
find Food/ -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i salt
```

or just the filenames (not the matched text)

```
find Food/ -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l salt
```

for more check "grep -h".

Multi-word phrases are possible

```
find Food/ -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "the quick brown fox"
```

But there is an added complication - HTML itself doesnt care about whitespace, so the phrase could be split over multiple lines. Which means the whitespace in the documents could be different to your search. eg the above wont match

#### the    quick
   brown fox

but tis valid html. Use Regex to workaround that...

```
find Food/ -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -iE "the[[:space:]]+quick[[:space:]]+brown[[:space:]]+fox"
```

but its starting to get messy.

You could put this in a .sh to so dont have to type all of that.

eg

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
find Food/ -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "$*"
```

which when saved as a file. And made executable, can be just run to run a test searc

```
find_in_food salt
```

will display a list of filenames.

(this is of course barely touching the surface of whats possible with this!)